# Cannot insert downloaded image into array Firebase Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase and Swift 4.

Image is downloaded from Firebase, but I couldn't figure out how to insert downloaded image into array of table view. This code return the same image into every array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? NewsTableViewCell

    let news: NewsList
    news = newsRows[indexPath.row]

    cell?.newsTitle.text = news.title
    cell?.newsDate.text = news.date

    let URL = self.newsImageReference
    print("abc")
    print(URL)
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: URL)

    storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let imageDownloaded = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        cell?.newsImg.image = imageDownloaded

        // should be 
        //cell?.newsImg = news.photo

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a Array for example `var customImages: [UIImage] = []`

and then add `customImages.append(UIImage(named: "image.png")!)` or

```
let imageDownloaded = UIImage(data: data as Data)
customImages.append(imageDownloaded)
```

in  storageRef.downloadURL Closure

and then `cell?.newsImg = customImages[indexPath.row]` if you have one image for all the cell you can do cell?.newsImg = customImages[0]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It returns fatal error: Index out range. 

storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
            
            var customImages: [UIImage] = []
            
            customImages.append(UIImage(data: data as Data)!)
            
            cell?.newsImg.image = customImages[indexPath.row]

Comment: create var customImages: [UIImage] = []  not in the closure But outside the function . 

for Example : 
var customImages: [UIImage] = [] 

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
....}
and create a func to append images into the array and then in cellForRowAt you can retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

1. First add one more property as **imgUrl** for your structure **NewsList** like **title, date**, etc
2. After that while you are fetching your other Firebase data, make a **Storage reference** and fetch your **images urls** for each record in your database and set these urls associated to your each **NewsList instance**.
3. After fetching data from database, just **reload** your tableview by calling **tableView.reloadData()** method.
4. Now rather than downloading each image by creating new Storage reference instance every time, you can use **SDWebImage** which is more appropriate solution for **downloading** an images from **remote urls** since it stores downloaded images into **cache** memory so that we don't need to download an image every time when **tableview cell reloads**. So modify your **cellForRowAt indexPath:** method as below:

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? NewsTableViewCell
      let news: NewsList
      news = newsRows[indexPath.row]
      cell?.newsTitle.text = news.title
      cell?.newsDate.text = news.date
      let imgURL = news.imgUrl
      cell?.newsImg.sd_setImage(with: imgURL) { (image, error, imgCacheType, url) in
           cell?.newsImg.image = image
      }
   }
   ```